# Elegant way to dispose of unmanaged resource in library used by multiple applications

Tags: c#, singleton, unmanaged, idisposable

A library in my application requires global use of an unmanaged resource.

To facilitate this, the library has the following:

There is a singleton class which inherits from `IDisposable`.

Acquisition of the unmanaged resource occurs in the `Instance()` method of the class.

The resource will always be accessed via the `MySingleton` object so this seems like a logical way of ensuring that the unmanaged resource is available when needed.

```
public class MySingleton : IDisposable
{
    private static MySingleton instance;

    public static MySingleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (typeof(MySingleton))
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new MySingleton();

                        // Acquire unmanaged resource here
                    }
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Release unmanaged resource here
    }
}
```

#### Problem

- The library with the above singleton is in use by multiple applications.
- To ensure that the unmanaged resource is correctly cleaned up, I need to call `MySingleton.Instance.Dispose()` within each application (usually in a `finally` block to ensure this happens even in `exception`al circumstances).
- If another application (i.e. entry-point) is created and the author forgets to call the `Dispose` method, this can result in the unmanaged resource not being cleaned up properly.

I tried added a destructor to the `MySingleton` class to do this but a breakpoint in there doesn't appear to be hit on application exit.  I'm guessing this is because the GC is non-deterministic and maybe the application is ending before the destructor for the static object is destroyed, but I'm not sure.

Is there an elegant way to ensure this resource will always be cleaned up, without relying on the client application explicitly calling `Dispose` to ensure this happens?

Comment: You *must* supply a destructor, calling Dispose() is only a nicety, it is not a requirement.  You cannot leave it the way it is, you'd at least have to use reference counting so a conscientious client programmer doesn't break somebody else's code.  Which won't work great either, you are better off removing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your static reference to the singleton will keep it alive regardless of whether anyone else is actually using it.  If you wish to detect when all outside references to your singleton have vanished without keeping it alive yourself, you must do something like one of the following:

1. Keep a `WeakReference` to the singleton, and return that every time someone asks for an object instance.  It's possible you may wish to keep both a long and a short `WeakReference`; a short one will be invalidated as soon as an object becomes eligible for finalization; a long one will remain valid until the GC cycle after the object is finalized.  If a short `WeakReference` gets invalidated, it will probably be necessary to create a new instance even if you have a long weak reference and even if the finalizer has not yet run.  On the other hand, you might need a long `WeakReference` to help handle the case where a new object is requested between the time the finalizer is requested on the old object and the time it actually runs.

   Keep a strong reference to the `real` singleton, but never expose it to anyone.  Instead, create a wrapper and store a `WeakReference` to it.  The finalizer of the wrapper should request that the singleton clean itself up.  This approach may be safer than the first approach in the scenario where code asks for the singleton instance between the time the old object becomes eligible for finalization and the time finalization actually occurs.  If all cleanup occurs through a single `Finalize` method, it will be possible for the get-singleton method to request that the finalizer to skip clean up, and know whether it made the request in time (if it didn't, it may have to wait for the finalizer to complete before creating a new instance).

   Keep a strong reference to the `real` singleton, and give every different entity that asks for it a different wrapper.  Keep a list of which wrappers have not yet had `finalize` called (keep at most a weak reference to the wrapper itself, but keep a strong reference to information about it) and, when the list is empty, perform the cleanup.  This approach is apt to be more complicated than the second, but it will make it possible to determine who is holding references to your object.

My recommendation would generally be approach #2 if your resource is one which cannot be recreated while an old instance exists.  A problem with approach #1 is that if there is more than one finalizable object associated with a resource, there may be a substantial interval during which the resource is partially cleaned up, and so the code may have no choice but to wait for other objects' finalizers to complete.  When using approach #2, if the singleton is requested while a finalizer is pending, either the request will come soon enough to prevent the finalizer from performing cleanup (in which case it need not wait for the finalizer to run, since the finalizer won't actually do anything), it will come after the finalizer has run (in which case the new instance can be created immediately), or it will come while the finalizer is performing cleanup (which is the worst case--the code must wait for the object's own cleanup to complete, but it won't have to wait for anyone else's finalization).

Answer (score 1):

Having a singleton implement IDisposable sounds wrong. Who is responsible for disposing of the object?

What is supposed to happen when two threads or two processes attempt to access the resource? Should the losers block or throw an exception?

I think you're better off taking a RAII approach where you have a class that implements IDisposable and is intended to only live for the time the resource is in use:

```
class MyResource : IDisposable { 
  public MyResource() {
    // Acquire resource here
  }

  public void Dispose() {
    // Free resource here, along with extra stuff to attempt
    // to catch situations where its not disposed 
  }
}
```

Then:

```
using( var r = new MyResource() ) {
  // Do work here.
}
```

You can't guarantee that every other dev using your library will remember to dispose of the class correctly but anyone who fails to use the class inside a using statement can be educated with a big sharp stick.

Answer (score 0):

About your destructor not being hit, look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx
The destructor is called but I don't think you can see that while debugging.
As for your singleton, it is obvious that it won't be called until the program exits since it is static.

About ensuring Dispose is called, I think the best you can do is inherit IDisposable and document the need to dispose. If there was a way to dispose things automatically, don't you think MS would have done that to SqlConnection or any other disposable class? BTW, I don't think it is a good practice to determine when an instance will be disposed in the class itself. This way you limit the use of your class and you can't know what the other component that will use your class want to do.